# What is the difference between "vice" and "deputy"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I know 'vice' and 'deputy' both mean "next in rank".  In Merriam-Webster, we have these definitions:

> [vice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vice):
>
> one that takes the place of *vice-chancellor*

In comparison to:

> [deputy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deputy):
>
> a person appointed as a substitute with power to act
>
> a second in command or assistant who usually takes charge when his or her superior is absent; specifically : *deputy sheriff*

So the two have clearly similar meanings, suggesting a person who does not normally carry the full responsibility of a given position, but who can perform those same duties as required or directed to.  Also, there are towns with Vice Mayors, and other towns with Deputy Mayors.

Can anyone tell their difference, such as usage or anything else?  Are they completely interchangeable and merely a matter of of a particular organization's preferences?

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Comment: @sesameblack- I have attempted to rescue your question, as I find it interesting myself.  It was a fairly large edit, though, so if I went too far feel free to re-edit, with my apologies.

Comment: I think that the first two answers to this Quora question address this pretty well:  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-vice-and-deputy

Comment: @cobaltduck- Thanks for your edit. I am still an English learner and struggling with writing. I think you did a good explanation and expansion.

Answer (score 6):

> **Vice**

Refers to the one second in command, next in authority to another person. It's used for people who are one step away to the highest authority. Their job is different from the higher person's. They're not authorized to act on behalf of the boss, unless they're told to do so.

Usually, a vice is someone, a person (maybe two persons, but not more). Not a group of people. Example:

> *vice president, vice admiral, vice chairman*

Meanwhile:

> **Deputy**

Refers to the one(s) appointed to act for another person (not necessarily next in command), to take their place on their behalf. What they do is subset to the higher person's authority. Usually, a person can have a number of deputies. Example:

> *Deputy manager, deputy sheriff.*

The word deputy is also commonly used in organizations. At where I work, we have six deputies (not six vices).

Comment: This is a solid answer. Where I work, we have a Director and three Associate Directors, one of whom is the "Principal Deputy" in the sense of this response. We also have committees, many of which single  vice-chairs.

Comment: I am not sure whether that is a solid answer. In my university, we have 'Executive Vice President for Research', 'Executive Vice President for Administrative Affairs', and 'Executive Vice President for Financial Affairs'. More than two people can have a vice position, as a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Vice is someone who is second highest in position and  can take up number one position in case of sudden demise of the person occupying number one position, without holding any fresh election. For example Vice President of USA,  Vice President of Union of India can take over as Presidents in case of sudden demise, removal or resignation of Presidents. Whereas Deputies are meant only to assist the people in number one position and cannot take over number one positions. For example,  Deputy Prime Minister of Union of India cannot become Prime Minister in case of his sudden demise.

Comment: This seems to conflict with the definition of deputy given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, 'vice-' (must have a hyphen) and 'deputy' are similar.
The differences are -

1. You have to combine 'vice-' with another word, either a noun or an adjective, e.g. vice-captain, vice-president, vice-presidential, etc.
   You must not use 'vice-' as a single word;
   While 'deputy' is a noun. You use 'deputy' as a word alone, e.g. I am acting as deputy till the manager returns. She is acting as deputy to the chairman of the board.
   Or, you use 'deputy' as a noun before another noun, e.g. She was appointed deputy head of the school. A former deputy chairman of the Democratic Party.
2. 'Vice-' originated from Latin *vice* 'in place of'. It means that when the most important person is away, you are in place of him or her during that time.
   In 'deputy', 'de' originated from Latin *de* 'away'. 'puty' originated from Latin *putare* 'consider'. It means that when the most important person is away, you consider what he or she is supposed to consider during that time. :)

Answer (score -1):

“Vice” refers to the one who is next in command and its usage is usually confined to a small number of people, whereas “Deputy” also refers the same but it is confined to considerably large number of people.

Comment: See e.g. large corporate American businesses where they have large numbers of Vice-Presidents.

Comment: "Confined...to [a] large number"? That doesn't sound very confined.

Answer (score -1):

Both *deputy X* and *vice X* are terms for official positions that are, in some way, secondary to that of X. The difference is that a part of the meaning of *deputy X* is that the powers of the person holding such a position are **derived** from the powers of X. A vice X, on the other hand, may have powers that are not derived from those of X. For example, the Vice President of the United States has the power to cast the deciding vote when the Senate is evenly divided; that power is bestowed on the Vice President directly by the Constitution, and is not in any way derived from the powers of the President (the President does not have such a power).